# Angular ngForm doesn't show value

Tags: angular, forms, typescript

The problem is, that my Form doesn't fetch the input data and show its value in console on submit.

I've put ngModel on every input element. I've also imported FormsModule in app.module.ts.

Here a screenshot of my console: [Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikxmJ.png)

**HTML:**

```
 <form class="w-50 mb-5 mt-5" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" NgModel required>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" placeholder="Future Family Name" NgModel required>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail" NgModel required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="package" value="{{selectedPackage}}" placeholder="{{selectedPackage}}" class="form-control" readonly NgModel>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="date" name="date" value="" placeholder="When is your wedding?" class="form-control" NgModel required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Your message.." NgModel></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="w-100 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

**Typescript:**

````
import {Component, Input, OnChanges, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css']
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  onSubmit(form: NgForm): void {
    console.log(form);
  }

}
```
````

Comment: `ngModel`, not `NgModel`

Comment: it should be `ngModel`, not `NgModel`, like I maybe unclearly stated in first comment.

Comment: @AJT_82 Thank you very much! That's it!

Comment: You are very welcome =)